# Is it good practice to set Samba's "server min protocol" to deny SMBv1-requests?

Tags: home-networking, samba, smb

I have a fairly small home network, consisting of:

- a NAS (running OpenMediaVault), NetBIOS-Name `FooBarNAS`
- a Raspberry Pi 2 with dnsmasq to provide DHCP/DNS services around the
  place,
- a modem (with deactivated DHCP, obviously),
- multiple clients running Windows >= 7 & some clients running linux variants

As far as I understand, my network is not accessible (i.e. `$ ping my.modem's.ip.adress` will fail) via the Internet.

---

About a year ago, I noticed that many websites, including [Microsoft's TechNet-blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2016/09/16/stop-using-smb1/) and [US-CERT](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/current-activity/2017/01/16/SMB-Security-Best-Practices), started to convince people to stop using SMBv1 on their servers (and clients).

Although I do not think that I have to cease using SMBv1 at all costs in my local network, I thought that it might be a good idea to give it a go, anyway. So in my NAS's `smb.conf`, I added `client min protocol = SMB2_10` and `server min protocol = SMB2_10` (SMBv2.1 was introduced with Windows 7, and since I do not own any devices with Windows versions below that, I thought that this would be a good start).

However, once I add this lines and restart samba, my computers cannot find the NAS anymore in the Explorer's "Network"-section, although I can still access it by typing `\\FooBarNAS` in the adress-bar (or using its IP-address). If I delete the lines again (and restart), `FooBarNAS` appears again.

I tried to add `netbios name = FooBarNAS` in `smb.conf`, but that did not change the behavior, either.

---

As this behavior is annoying (especially for those people in the house who do not like to use the address bar), and I am unable find any definitive information towards the topic in the Internet, my question is:

**In home networks, is the security increased by "switching off" SMBv1 in Samba?**

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is very simple,
Network browsing is using SMBv1!!!
In the latest SNIA SDC Microsoft announced about the death of SMBv1(disable by default - register) but still the network browsing will work over SMBv1.

That is why you could not see your device.
Try to modify only the server : `server min protocol = SMB2_10`
And leave the Client to support SMBv1

Comment: thanks for the answer; however, that does not make a difference. I know the issue, but frankly, I don't really understand why someone would design it that way...that's why I'm asking if SMBv1 is bad in a local network.

Comment: We know that the SMBv1 has a security issue (see [link](https://www.grahamcluley.com/global-ransomware-outbreak-happening-right-now/) ) , and it too old ,the network browser architecture is old as SMB, we asked Microsoft what they are planing to do with this issue, and they told us "we are talking about change the Browsing" 
If you are using it only internally that will not make any difference, your machines (as describe) are support SMBv2, so if one of your windows will not support SMBv1 it sill work over SMBv2.
And one more secret the SMBv1 is not entirely disable(Browsing will still work)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Run secpol.msc

I had to disable this here to get mine to work.

Comment: Thank you for the tip; unfortunately, this did not change the behavior. By `I had to disable this` you mean that you changed it to `Send NTLMv2 response only. Refuse LM & NTLM`, right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  View the log files for error messages and turn the debugging level up.

Comment: Oops, forgot to answer. the logs, as far as I see, turn up nothing at all. Or are we talking about very specific logs that I don't know of?